# React native - ScrollView not working in android

Tags: react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I used my scrollview in react-native inside flex, It works on web but it doesn't works on my android phone

Here is the mine code -

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={styles.box1} >
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.box2, { height: this.state.height }]} />
          <View style={styles.box1} >
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ height: this.state.height + 50 })}>
              <Text>Click me to grow the purple section</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my stylesheet -

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  box1: {
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  box2: {
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'purple'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Removing the property `flex: 1` from `contentContainerStyle`. If flex is required you can go for `flexGrow: 1` instead of `flex`.

For more on [contentContainerStyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle)